# Can I update from 7.34 to 7.41 directly? What is the safest way to do so?

Tags: 7, updating

I have a site built using Drupal 7.34, and now I want the core to be upgraded to 7.41 and would like to know the safest way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Drupal Core is self-contained in that any forward version of Drupal contains all the updates of intermediary versions of Drupal you are missing. So, you don't have to install and update Drupal manually through every single version of Drupal that is released.

The recommended way is to simply overwrite your drupal site files as per the distributed documentation with Drupal. Put your site in Maintenance Mode and run the update script.

Alternatively, you can upgrade Drupal via Patches:
https://fuerstnet.de/en/drupal-upgrade-easy-way

Comment: Your answer is excellent as it clarifies Drupal is self-contained and also offers different ways to perform the update. I believe you should also add Drush as it's one of the best methods to do the update. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Using drush to upgrade is for me the best, safest (as it does backups) and fastest way to upgrade Drupal, so:

Backup your databases and your files first.

```
drush archive-dump
```

Then to update core you can run

```
drush up drupal
```

Comment: does this method overwrite the `.gitignore` `.htaccess` file and `robots.txt` file? if yes, then if you made modifications to these files, you would lose them. So then you would need to have a backup of these files and re-upload them.

Comment: Yes this method overwrites the files you mention. It's not recommended to make modifications to those files or any files that come with core. If you need to modify those files check those modules for example: https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess and https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt

Answer (score 3):

> Can i upgrade from 7.34 to 7.41 directly? What is the safest way to do
>   so?

Yes you can.

**Step 1)**

Backup your server's Database and your Drupal folder.

**Step 2)**

Follow this Video Tutorial [Update Drupal Core to newer version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj3Ujsjnqkw) which is the safest way to do it.

**Quick Summary of the Video**

1. Download Drupal 7.41 zip file and extract its contents.
2. Delete the `Sites folder` and also `.gitignore` `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` files.
3. Upload everything onto your server and overwrite the files.

**Once you uploaded and overwritten everything on your server**

4. Put your website in `Maintenace Mode` (Configuration > Maintenance Mode)
5. Go to `www.yourwebsite.com/update.php` and update the database
6. Take your website out of `Maintenace Mode`
7. Delete `Install.php` from your server. (not covered in the video, but its good to do it)